# how to use __UHADD8 in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

I have seen this in one library function of the STM32 microcontroller. I have referred to this link https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0491/i/ARMv6-SIMD-Instruction-Intrinsics/--uhadd8-intrinsic but I couldn't get it. Please, someone, explain with an example.

Comment: There's already an example in that link.  Can you explain what about it is not clear, or how your desired example would be different from that one?

Comment: I guess maybe one helpful note is that what ARM calls "halved addition" is more commonly called the "average" or "mean" of two numbers.  You add them and divide by two.  This is done for each of the four pairs of corresponding bytes in the 32-bit inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Above link has already good enough explanation and even some example. So only providing some sample example here with some numeric value to make explanation clear.
As explained and shown on above link `__uhadd8`

1. split two integer and bytes
2. add respective bytes(i.e. byte1 of a with byte1 of b, byte2 of a with byte2 of b, and so on)
3. halve resultant value(i.e. shift left by a bit) and pack resultant byte as a result(i.e., [resultbte4][resultbyte2][resultbyte2][resultbyte1]).

Below example with some numeric value.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <arm_acle.h>

    int main(int argc,char** argv){
            int ret = 0, a[] = {0x01010101,0x02020202,0xffffffff,0xffffffff}, b[] = {0x10101010,0x10101010,0x01010101,0xffffffff};
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); ++i ) {
                    ret = __uhadd8(a[i],b[i]);
                    printf("a:0x%x,b:0x%x,ret:0x%x\n",a[i],b[i],ret);
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

Output of above code will be:

> ```
> # arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc a.c -static && ./a.out
> a:0x1010101,b:0x10101010,ret:0x8080808 
> a:0x2020202,b:0x10101010,ret:0x9090909 
> a:0xffffffff,b:0x1010101,ret:0x80808080
> a:0xffffffff,b:0xffffffff,ret:0xffffffff
> ```

Note: As commented by @Nate Eldredge in comment, in simple term result is byte wise average of to given integer.